# How to switch htop tab?

Tags: htop

I recently see that there is new "I/O" (blue one) on htop, how to switch to that tab?
[image]

Comment: Was looking for the IO and I didn't had the tab, to enable it => https://superuser.com/questions/1716067/how-to-make-htop-to-display-network-info-and-io-info-like-this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK found it XD

literally <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>

from  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html